# I want to add an alert in the if else statement. How do I do that?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I want to add an alert inside the if and else if. If the user does not enter anything in the prompt box the alert triggers. Also if the user enters a number the prompt it will say that the user entered a number. How do do that?

```js
let myForm2 = document.querySelector('.form2');
let pDisplay1 = document.querySelector('.display4');
myForm2.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let uname = document.querySelector('.inputName2').value;
  if (uname == null) {


  } else if (isNaN(uname) == false) {

  } else {
    pDisplay1.innerHTML = `Welcome to the program ${uname}`;
  }

})
```

```html
<p> Activity 6</p>
<form class="form2" method="get">
  <label>Full Name: <input type="text" class="inputName2"></label>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<p class="display4"></p>
```

Comment: have go at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.querySelector('.className').value` will  return a string.

`string.trim()` removes the whitespaces and if the `length === 0` it means that the input is empty or has only whitespaces which you generally want to treat as empty. If you consider space is a valid input you don't have to use trim().

The + sign will convert a string into a number otherwise you could use parseInt(variable).

`Number.isInteger(variable)` will return true if the variable is an integer.

You could also write `!isNaN(+uname)` or `+uname !== Number.NaN`

```
myForm2.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let uname = document.querySelector('.inputName2').value;
    if (uname.trim().length === 0) {
        alert('You should write something');
    } else if (Number.isInteger(+uname)) {
        alert('You wrote a number');
    } else {
        pDisplay1.innerHTML = `Welcome to the program ${uname}`;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining every little things. Thanks a lot. Learned something new.

Answer (score 2):

**Empty string is not equal to null**, replace `uname==null` with `uname==''`, after the replacement, you can identify the situation that the user did not input, if it is more strict, you can also use [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to remove whitespace and then do condition review